# Accessing http headers in .NET Core 3.0 Api

Tags: asp.net-core, httpcontext

Inject IHttpContextAccessor through constructor.

```cs
       private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
       public Handler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) 
            {
                _userManager = userManager;
                _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
//access header values.
var header = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
```